# Connection errors after changing MAC address on Wifi adapter linux

Tags: mac-address

I've looked everywhere for anything on this but i can't find anything!
Whenever i edit the mac address on my ALFA USB network adapter(using macchanger or from network-manager), I can't connect to ANY network altogether. This means I have to revert back using `macchanger -p` for it to work again.
Is this a hardware issue? Is it normal behavior?

I've also tested this on a virtual machine, same results there as well.

Comment: I think it's normal, at least since some years ago ;)

Comment: Why though, and how can i overwrite this behavior

Comment: Why do you think you need to? MAC addresses don't pass borders.

Comment: The question isn't why i think i need to, It's that i need to and I want to know why i can't ... Anyway, I've found a temporary solution that requires a reboot, but there must be an easier way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
Apparently Network Manager takes issue with any attempt to change your MAC address, because taking the adapter down "improperly" causes it to mount it back with the previous MAC, causing an error in the process. Take these steps to fix the issue:

1. Go to network manager and disable Wifi from there (check if it's worked by typing `ifconfig [adapter] down`, you should get an error saying it doesn't exist.
2. Use a terminal and change your mac from there `ifconfig [adapter] hw ether [MAC]`
3. Re-enable Wifi from Network Manager, and check to see if it worked using `ifconfig` or similar methods.

Alternatively you can do it from boot, just edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and add in `pre-up ifconfig [adapter] hw ether [MAC]`, this will work when the adapter is connected and throw a `Failed` at boot if it's disconnected(no big deal thb)